# Making normal tableview cell to scale according to amount of text

Tags: objective-c, uikit, uitableview

Hey I need to make my tableview cells size to adjust by the amount of text there is it annoying when the text goes like this "Some text her...". Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

textLabel property of UITableViewCells is a UILabel so, just set:

```
cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = n;
```

and the text will be at most n lines.